# Synthesize via design compiler, report_constraint show capacitance violated

Tags: synthesis

(1) After successfully synthesize, report_constraint shows there is capacitance violation.

```
dc_shell> report_constraint -all_violators -significant_digits 6
****************************************
Report : constraint
        -all_violators
Design : SCPU_SRAM_8BIT_ALU_TOP
Version: D-2010.03-SP2
Date   : Fri Apr 29 16:39:03 2016
****************************************
   max_capacitance            Required        Actual
   Net                      Capacitance    Capacitance       Slack
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
 SCPU_ALU_CTRL_UUT_REG_B[3] 0.170640       0.172200       -0.001560 (VIOLATED)
```

(2) However, there are no timing violations, and the slack is positive.

```
dc_shell> report_timing -significant_digits 6
****************************************
Report : timing
        -path full
        -delay max
        -max_paths 1
Design : SCPU_SRAM_8BIT_ALU_TOP
Version: D-2010.03-SP2
Date   : Fri Apr 29 17:09:55 2016
****************************************
  ......................

  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  data required time                                             4.648854
  data arrival time                                              -4.646599
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  slack (MET)      

                                          0.002255
```

(3) I've tried to change the constraints by using the command `set_max_capacitance 5 ${My_Design}`. Yet, the violation is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I check many reports, the report_net info shows a large fanout related to the pin.

```
Net                 Fanout     Fanin      Load   Resistance    Pins
----------------------------------------------------------------------
SCPU_ALU_CTRL_UUT_REG_B[3]  11     1      0.17         0.00      12
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Therefore, I change the constraint named set_max_fanout to 10 and then synthesize again. Problem solved!

Comment: That's a good solution, however the violation is at a negligible level for pre-layout.